# Rails new default app is not working on heroku server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have created a new app with command rails new publication

I have run it on local machine(Windows 7 machine) with rails s command. It works fine and shows the rails default page.

when I pushed it to heroku server by command git push heroku master it is uploaded successfully but does not work . Its shows error

https://quiet-spire-3568.herokuapp.com/

here is my heroku logs

```html
Rockman@ROCKMAN-PC /c/Sites/publication (master)
$ heroku logs
Your version of git is 1.9.4.. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:31.675313+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:31.675320+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-11 04:11:31] INFO  going to shutdown ...
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:31.675323+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exiting
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:31.893442+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 37363 -e production`
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:32.788181+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 143
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:35.834860+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-11 04:11:35] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:35.835340+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-11 04:11:35] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=37363
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:35.834888+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-11 04:11:35] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-02-25) [x86_64-linux]
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:36.299932+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to up
←[33m2015-04-11T04:11:45.483107+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path="/" host=quiet-spire-3568.herokuapp.com request_id=33964df
4-4d3a-4271-bb3f-52c12102e812 fwd="103.230.106.8" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=88ms status=404 bytes=1829
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.401590+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Rails 4.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:37363
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.401583+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Booting WEBrick
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.401592+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.401594+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.401596+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 103.230.106.8 at 2015-04-11 04:11:45 +0000
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479861+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479869+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479871+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_
exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479873+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_e
xceptions.rb:30:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479875+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_ap
p'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479877+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block i
n call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479878+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.
rb:68:in `block in tagged'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479880+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.
rb:26:in `tagged'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479883+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479882+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.
rb:68:in `tagged'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479885+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reques
t_id.rb:21:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479886+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479888+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479890+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/
local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479891+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static
.rb:113:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479893+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479894+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479896+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479897+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479899+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479900+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'

←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479901+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479903+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479904+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479906+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-11T04:11:45.479907+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[32m2015-04-11T04:21:24.153651+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy 68bcbac by jaforrockman695@gmail.com
←[32m2015-04-11T04:21:24.153651+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v8 created by jaforrockman695@gmail.com
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:24.310724+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from up to starting
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:27.005169+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 52295 -e production`
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:27.731941+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568788+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568781+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-11 04:21:28] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568790+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568792+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568794+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568795+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:35:in `run
'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568797+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568799+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in
 `start'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568802+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.
rb:75:in `tap'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568801+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.
rb:80:in `block in server'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568805+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.
rb:39:in `run_command!'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568807+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top
(required)>'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568808+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   bin/rails:4:in `require'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568810+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568804+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.
rb:75:in `server'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568818+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-11 04:21:28] INFO  going to shutdown ...
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568890+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exiting
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:28.568821+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-11 04:21:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:29.588949+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 143
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:30.425566+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-11 04:21:30] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:30.425592+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-11 04:21:30] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-02-25) [x86_64-linux]
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:30.426106+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-11 04:21:30] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=52295
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:31.018560+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to up
←[33m2015-04-11T04:21:37.891471+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path="/" host=quiet-spire-3568.herokuapp.com request_id=065981b
6-5f85-48c4-ac54-cd6ecd99a450 fwd="103.230.106.8" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=63ms status=404 bytes=1829
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.834914+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Booting WEBrick
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.834921+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Rails 4.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:52295
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.834923+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.834925+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.834927+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 103.230.106.8 at 2015-04-11 04:21:37 +0000
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886595+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886602+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886605+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_
exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886606+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_e
xceptions.rb:30:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886608+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_ap
p'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886610+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block i
n call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886615+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.
rb:26:in `tagged'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886613+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.
rb:68:in `block in tagged'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886616+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.
rb:68:in `tagged'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886618+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886619+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reques
t_id.rb:21:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886621+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886623+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886625+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/
local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886628+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886626+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static
.rb:113:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886629+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886631+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886632+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886633+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886638+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886635+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'

←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886636+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886639+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-11T04:21:37.886642+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
```

And her is my gemfile

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'



gem 'rails', '4.2.1'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do

  gem 'sqlite3'
 
  gem 'byebug'

 
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end


gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

ruby "2.0.0"
```

I have changed config\environment\production.rb

config.assets.compile = false
to
  config.assets.compile = true

Please help me

Comment: Can you show your routes files

Comment: Routes file is the default routes I didn't even create any static page / controller or scaffold. I just wanted to see the default home page on heroku server

Comment: Try setting   config.serve_static_assets = true

Comment: Also try adding gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production  to your gem file and push again  to heroku

Comment: Is your root path database dependent? If you're root path works on your local machine, it might be that you didn't initialize/seed your database on heroku.

Answer (score 1):

The default "welcome" page is only served up in development, so it's normal to get a 404 in production.

That page is provided by a controller and templates that are part of the rails gem and as you can see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb#L22) the routes to it are only added in development.

Answer (score 0):

please set your root in routes with something like:

```
root to: 'pages#main'
```

where page is controller name and main is the method

Comment: Thanks to all I Understood the matter from all of you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually configure your home page in production since the default one only applies to development mode.

To paraphrase the documentation, do something like this:

```
rails generate controller Greetings
```

Then go to `app/controllers/greetings_controller.rb` and modify slightly:

```
class GreetingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @message = "Hello, how are you today?"
  end
end
```

Then go to `app/views/greetings/index.html.erb` and do this:

```
<h1>A Greeting for You!</h1>
<p><%= @message %></p>
```

Finally in `config/routes.rb`:

```
root :to => 'greetings#index'
```

Incidentally, this will also let you hit `/greetings` too.

Answer (score 0):

In your config/application.rb, try adding this to the last line (before the "end"s...

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

If you're pushing to Heroku with Git, you'll want to re-commit with this line. Otherwise start a new Heroku app with this line included. Idk about any other changes you've made in trying to solve this, but when I used to use Heroku, this line was *necessary* for it to work. Good luck!